# How to show layout's label or description in a custom Layout Builder settings form

Tags: 9, layout-builder

I have successfully made custom layouts and a custom settings form, something like this: https://www.codimth.com/blog/web/drupal/how-add-custom-settings-layouts-drupal-8-9

I want the custom settings form to include the layout's label and description as I have defined them in the layouts.yml file.

Like, at the top of the form before my settings, the name of the layout and then the description. I don't want to have to make a new Class for each layout just to show different label and description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague figured it out :D

```
public function buildConfigurationForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $configuration = $this->getConfiguration();
  $definition = $this->getPluginDefinition();
  $form['feature_set_info'] = [
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#markup' => '<div class="form-item"><div class="isu-layout-form-title">' . $definition->getLabel() . '</div><p class="description isu-form-element-description">' . $definition->getDescription() . '</p></div></div>',
  ];
  // The rest of my form
  return $form;
}
```

In particular `$definition = $this->getPluginDefinition();` and then use it as `$definition->getLabel()` and `$definition->getDescription()`.